# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for mathplotlib

Tags: python-3.x

[screen shot of the error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MXx3.png) While installing 'matplotlib' I'm facing issue as it shows error message

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mathplotlib (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mathplotlib".

I also tried updating it but no the problem is still there.

how to install the library?

Comment: Thank you for replying this fast. I tried removing h and then installing it but it is showing  'WARNING: The wheel package is not available.' along with this a big error message specified in 270 words and then again and again downloading the different versions of 'matplotlib'. I'll be really great full if you can suggest something.

Comment: It is likely there is no precompiled matplotlib version for your platform. Which means you'd have to compile matplotlib yourself; which is likely what those error messages are about. What operating system do you use? And what Python version?

Comment: I'm using X64 bit windows and python version 3.10.0. I tried installing wheel package but even after that one new error message, stating:- Warning: No matching distribution found for matplotlib

Comment: If you look at https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files , you'll see that there is no Python 3.10 binary version of Matplotlib yet, since the most recent release of Matplotlib is from a few months *before* Python 3.10 was released. You'll have to wait a bit, downgrade to 3.9, or try and compile Matplotlib yourself (which requires a C compiler, among others).

Comment: See also https://pythonspeed.com/articles/switch-python-3.10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the name of the library it is `matplotlib` and not `mathplotlib` (*mat* not *math*).

Try installing again with

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Thank you for replying this fast. I tried removing h and then installing it but it is showing 'WARNING: The wheel package is not available.' along with this a big error message specified in 270 words and then again and again downloading the different versions of 'matplotlib'. I'll be really great full if you can suggest something